# javascript confirm box always return true

Tags: javascript

I'm working with java and using jstl in my jsp page. In my customer page, when I delete a customer, it will show a confirm box. But when I choose yes or no, it till delete this customer. This is my javascript code:

```
<a load-in="mainNotify" href='<c:url value="customer/delete?id=${ item.id }" />'
onclick="return confirm('Delete ?');">
<i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

How can I resolved this?

Comment: It is working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/uZZ5n/

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're still dealing with a click to an `a` element, and the browser behavior here is to navigate to the destination URL -- which in your case appears to be the delete action.

To prevent this, you need to cancel the click event *if* the user says "no" on the `confirm`. So something more like:

The JavaScript:

```
function onDelete() {
  if (!confirm('Delete?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<a load-in="mainNotify" href='<c:url value="customer/delete?id=${ item.id }" />' onclick="onDelete()">
<i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!confirm('Delete?')) event.preventDefault();
```

Give this a try